# Avoid new break line in groovy template

Tags: templates, groovy, template-engine, gstring

I have `YAML file` with my configuration name **applications.yaml**, this data will be my bindings:

```
applications:
- name: service1
  port: 8080
  path: /servier1
- name: service2
  port: 8081
  path: /service2
```

Then I have a template file **applications.config**:

```
<% applications.each { application ->  %>
ApplicationName: <%= application.name %>
<% } $ %>
```

And putting all together:

```
@Grab('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17')
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

Yaml parser = new Yaml()
Map data = parser.load(("applications.yaml" as File).text)

String template_content = new File('applications.config').text
def binding = [applications: data.applications]

def template = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine().createTemplate(template_content).make(binding)
println template.toString()
```

The issues is now: the output of this process is:

```
ApplicationName: service1

ApplicationName: service2
```

But I want this:

```
ApplicationName: service1
ApplicationName: service2
```

I do not know why are those extra spaces there. I will like to remove those but I do not see how or when or what is putting those **new or breaking lines**.

Thank you.

Comment: You tried putting the applications config template code all on one line?

Comment: nope, I am trying to do is just one line after another without the extra spaces in the output. @tim_yates, as you can see the output, is adding new lines in the loop but I don't want that.

Comment: Yes that why I suggested removing the extra newlines from your template

Comment: Why everything in a single line, what happens if I want an if/else or nested loops? I will like to know if there is a way to avoid that extra-space, for example in jinja2 I can use ```{% my_value -%}``` where the **-** allows me to skip new lines but I will like to know if the template has something like that or a configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What I observed (from answer, comments and some practice) is :** All `new Lines`, we created inside the file `applications.config` are considered as `new line` in the output. As **daggett** said it is a default thing.

So Here I just want to show the possible `config` file format, where can be applied some `conditional logic` as u asked and looks ok for me. ex : `if()`

**application.config :**

```
<% applications.each { application ->
 if (application.valid) {%>\
Type :<%=application.valid%>
ApplicationName:<%=application.name%>
Path:<%=application.path%>
Port:<%=application.port%>
<%} else{%>\
--------------------
Found invalid Application : <%= application.name %>
--------------------\
<%}}%>
```

**application.yaml**

```
applications:
- name: service1
  port: 8080
  path: /servier1
  valid: true
- name: service2
  port: 8081
  path: /service2
  valid: false
```

**code.groovy**

```
@Grab('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17')
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

Yaml parser = new Yaml()
Map data = parser.load(("applications.yaml" as File).text)

String template_content = new File('applications.config').text

def binding = [applications: data.applications]
def template = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine().createTemplate(template_content).make(binding)
println template.toString()
```

**Output :**

```
Type :true
ApplicationName:service1
Path:/servier1
Port:8080
--------------------
Found invalid Application : service2
--------------------
```

Comment: Thank you both for your answers but this @Bhanuchander is the solution I was looking for. Using the ```\``` worked really fine and also allows me to remove the newlines in other places.

Answer (score 2):

look at your template for example from notepad++ (JSP language):

[image]

at the end of first line `<% applications.each { application -> %>` there is a `CRLF` that will be printed out before each `Application`

and in the next line another `CRLF` that will be printed after each `Application`.

so you have two `CRLF` between each two apps

Comment: how do I remove those from my vscode? I am trying to remove those?

Comment: unfortunately, standard template does not support `-%>` to suppress new line. so, if you want to keep multiline template, then hide new-lines that should not be printed into `<% ... %>` code sections. Like that: `CRLF %>Application: ...` or use single-liner fot this case: `<% applications.each { println "ApplicationName: $it" } %>`

Comment: So everything in a single line? what happens when I want to use if/else or a more complex structure? really a shame there is no way to avoid this!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid the newlines is to fix your template like below

```
<% applications.each { application ->  %>ApplicationName: <%= application.name %>
<% } $ %>
```

**Results**

```sh
$ groovy test.groovy
ApplicationName: service1
ApplicationName: service2
```

or handle the newlines in code like below

```
@Grab('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17')
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

Yaml parser = new Yaml()
Map data = parser.load(("applications.yaml" as File).text)

String template_content = new File('applications.config').text
def binding = [applications: data.applications]

def template = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine().createTemplate(template_content).make(binding)
def output = template.toString().replaceAll(/^\n|\n$/, "").replaceAll(/\n{2,}/,"\n")
println output
```

**Results**

```sh
$ groovy test.groovy
ApplicationName: service1
ApplicationName: service2
```